# Remove Dynamic Parent Element in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm populating a table with PHP code that talks to my database. The PHP echo's code back into the table as separate rows. Each row has a delete button and I want to make that delete button remove the row from the DOM.

```
echo "<tr><td data-creator='$creator'>{$comment}<a class='deleteComment' 
data-role='button' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='notext';></a></td></tr>";
```

// php code ends

```
<script type='javascript'>

$(".deleteComment").click(function () {
$(this).parent().remove();
});
</script>
```

This won't work. And when I put a console.log statement into the .deleteComment function, nothing prints to the console when I click on the delete button within a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set up a [quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9PBd/). Works like a charm for me. I don't see any mistake. A more complete example of your code would be good.

Did you try to log like this? What will it show?

```
$(".deleteComment").click(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});​
```

Comment: thanks – I should have shown you the full code and you would have been able to see that I had failed to create an HTML element for the delete button. works fine now.